# Multiple line chart

Tags: r, plot, lines

I am trying to plot two line curves on one chart using plot() and then lines().
But with this the second line curve goes out of chart and is half plotted.

```
plot(A, main="Bot",xlab="Days",ylab="$$$",type='l',col = 'Green')
lines(B, main="Bot",col = 'Red')
```

Am I missing any parameter for the scale?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the minimum value for y on the red curve,  then add  the parameter `ylim=c(MinY, 4000)` into your *first* plot.